# Connect to 3G dongle using wifi

Tags: python, at-command

Under a linux ubuntu 12.4 operating system I managed to communicate with a TP-link 3G dongle after switching the mode of it. So, I am able to send and receive SMS for example.

For establishing a internet connection I use `WVdial` which is quite convenient. However, I don't have any manage over it and i cant control it.

The Question, is there any python library to establish an `ppp` connection with 3G dongle or, any thing can wrap `WVdial` so i will have some kind of control over it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) to connect to it, then you can send all the custom AT commands that you want.